# How to update/add the new/existing contents of a dictionary inside a list from a list reference

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dynamic list of contents which varies on timely basis. Based on the contents of the dynamic list, I need to add/update the dictionary inside the another list.

```
list1 = ["data1", "data2", "data3", ..... "dataN"]
list_dict1 = [{"Id" : "data1"}, {"Id": "data2"}]
```

As you can see the list1 contains "N" number of items which is not static so the value and the quantity of the items will be changed on timely manner. Now, **list_dict1** is depending on **list1** to add/update the dictionary data. Right now, in list_dict1 have the values for data1 the requirement is to automatically add/update the dictionary inside **list_dict1** with the count of items or the values from **list1**.

I can do it the following way:

```
# Example if list1 has only one element

count = len(list1)
if count == 1:
   list_dict1 = [{"Id" : list1[0]}]

# Example if list1 have only two elements

count = len(list1)
if count == 2:
   list_dict1 = [{"Id" : list1[0]},{"Id" : list1[1]}] 

# Example if list1 have only four elements

count = len(list1)
if count == 2:
   list_dict1 = [{"Id" : list1[0]},{"Id" : list1[1]},{"Id" : list1[2]},{"Id" : list1[3]}] 

....
```

but this way, if I have 100 elements in the list I need to write 100 if conditions, and need to manually update the list_dict1 accordingly. Is there anyway to automatically write/update the **list_dict1** with the count of items and the respective items from **list1**

Comment: Use [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) or [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: You are simply forming a new List each time which can be dome using comprehension. But is not clear what you mean by update the List nor what value there is in the Dictionaries since all use the same key `Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_dict1 = [{"Id" : l} for l in list1]
```

Does exactly what you do with your if statements?

But somehow I don't quite get what you are trying to achieve. It might help to explain your goal somewhat better.